# I'm trying to bulkify the update of parent field based on child

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

I've written a trigger that is called when child record is inserted. I want the room(Parent) status to be updated to Occupied when the patient(Child) closure is set to false.

Here's the code that I had work once and now I can't seem to find the error

```
public static void roomStatusOccupied(List<Patient__c> pList){
        Set<Id> roomIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Patient__c p:pList){
            if(p.Closure__c==false){
                roomIds.add(p.Rooms__c);
            }
        }
        if(roomIds.size()>0){
            List<Rooms__c> toBeUpdated = new List<Rooms__c>();  
            for (Rooms__c room : [SELECT Id,Status__c FROM Rooms__c WHERE Name IN :roomIds]) {
                room.Status__c='Occupied';
                toBeUpdated.add(room);
            }
            update toBeUpdated;
        }
    }
```

I'd written a different code to work not just on insert but also update but that doesn't work either.
What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying the rooms by their name instead of their database identifier.

Instead of `WHERE Name IN` use `WHERE Id IN`.

An improved version of your snippet, with an early return and a more selective query, would look like this:

```
public static void roomStatusOccupied (List<Patient__c> pList) {
    Set<Id> roomIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Patient__c p : pList) {
        if (!p.Closure__c) {
            roomIds.add(p.Rooms__c);
        }
    } 

    // check if rooms are empty and return early if there's nothing to
    // execute below
    if (roomIds.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    List<Rooms__c> rooms = new List<Rooms__c>();  
    
    // fetch rooms and update their status, but only for those rooms that are
    // not occupied already
    for (Rooms__c room : [SELECT Id, Status__c FROM Rooms__c WHERE Name IN :roomIds AND Status__c != 'Occupied']) {
        room.Status__c = 'Occupied';
        rooms.add(room);
    }

    // no need to worry if "rooms" is empty or not.
    // if it is, the system is smart enough to not consume a DML
    update rooms;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This code makes sense and the test class seems to pass it but when manually creating a new patient it doesn't seem to work. There may be an issue somewhere else ? Any further advice is much appreciated

Comment: You should probably look at the code that calls this `roomStatusOccupied` method then.